# How to convert string to numeric in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

I'm getting

> "ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type numeric: "NOS-Numbers" "

while running query

Datatype:

```
quantity numeric(15,3)
```

query:

```
insert into report_data(quantity)
select case 
         when p.product= 'OUTRIGHT' then 
           case 
             when sum(convert_to_integer(p.qty,0)) > 0 then 'NOS-Numbers' 
             else to_number('') 
            end 
           else to_number('') 
         end
from product_details
```

please help to get this resolved.

Comment: Yes, You try to put string into numeric field. It is Your command? I try to gueass main idea, but cannot

Comment: Of course this fails. You can't store `'NOS-Numbers'` in a column defined as `numeric`- it's not a number. Store `NULL` instead. `to_number('')` is also invalid. You can't convert an empty string to a number

Comment: What result do you expect from this: `to_number('')` ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot store strings in a numeric colums, and storing display data is generally a bad idea. Use instead `NULL` for an unknown value, and convert this to a better displayable value when fetching. E.g.:

```
SELECT COALESCE(quantity, 'NOS-Numbers') FROM report_data;
```

will return `'NOS-Numbers'` for `NULL`, and the value of `quantity` otherwise.